# Integral of a lsc function is lsc?

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis, bochner-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a lower semicontinuous function.  Then is it true that $$
\begin{aligned}
L^2_{\nu}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d);\mathbb{R}^D)&\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]
\\g&\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x,g(x)) \nu(dx)
\end{aligned}
$$ is a proper, lower-semicontinuous, and convex operator? 
Here $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $L^2_{\nu}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d);\mathbb{R}^D)$ is the corresponding Bochner-Lebesgue space.

Comment: You seem to mistaken $\mu$ and $\nu$. Also, $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ in the integral is redundant

Comment: The operator is defined on space of which functions?

Comment: Without any function space for $g$, this is impossible to answer. But by the title, I was expecting the question to be about lower semi-continuity of $$ x\mapsto\int f(x,y)\nu(dy)$$ for a function $f$ which is lower semi-continuous w.r.t. $x$. If this is what you are actually interested in, you can prove it in one line via Fatou's Lemma and the $\liminf$-characterization of lower semi-continuity. If it isn't, ignore this comment.

Comment: Convex, sure. It's even linear (if well-defined).

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, it should have read as a composition operator...I made the corrections and clarified which space I want to act on...

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want the codomain to be $(-\infty,\infty]$? Unless you somehow exclude $f\equiv-1$, the operator can also take the value $-\infty$.

Comment: But does restricting the codomain to $(-\infty,\infty)$ help?